# Understanding memory allocations in C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

When I run a platform that uses the code below, `valgrind` shows that a huge amount of memory is spent on `push_back()` operation in the 3D vector. Therefore, it is not possible to finish counting another large-scale task that exploits this code (the process itself is destroyed due to insufficient memory).

I would like to understand how to modify and/or optimize the code so that the allocation of memory for such vectors does not lead to such unfortunate results?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a; 
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> a_3d;
std::vector<double> b(n, -10000.0);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ...; i++)
        a.push_back(b);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ...; i++)
        a_3d.push_back(a); // <- painful moment...
```

Comment: That is a whole lot of copying happening there - what exactly is the desired result (e.g.: what is `a_3d` used for)

Comment: `std::vector<T>` preallocates memory according to the given capacity on construction. Also the underlying `malloc()` calls will always reserve fixed blocks like 1k or so, regardless if you would use that much or not.

Comment: You are always pushing back the same element? Why not initialise the vector `a_3d` then and not use any loops? That would be faster. Still, you get overhead from cache misses, so the ultimate optimisation is to not use nested `std::vector`, instead having own class that allocates contiguous memory and calculates proper index.

Comment: What exactly are the `...` values, and what is the value of `n`, and how big do you expect `n * ? * ? * sizeof(double)` to be?

Comment: If you actually want to model a 3D array/tensor, using nested vector is almost never a good idea. Instead, use a single, flat `std::vector<double>` and calculate the indices for subsetting yourself, using fixed strides based on the tensor dimensions.

Comment: @UnholySheep `a_3d` is used for some additional calculations like `x = Metric(a_3d[i][j][k])`

Comment: This should be fine, assuming `n` is a small number like `5` or so, and the `...` is a small number like `5` or so.

Comment: `std::reserve()` doesn't helps to avoid this trouble. So I think the best idea is to use some different structure, but not 3D `std::vector`...

Comment: Try *calculating* (lower bounds for) the amount of memory consumed by `b`.  From that, you'll be able to calculate lower bounds for the memory consumed by `a` (in the first loop).  Once you have that, you'll be able to calculate lower bounds for the memory consumed by `a_3d` in the second loop.   You'll find that the memory consumed by *each call* (they ADD UP) of `a_3d.push_back(a)` is proportional to `n` *multiplied by* the number of iterations of the second loop - which grows really quickly (and, unless your machine has a LOT of memory) can quickly exceed the amount of available memory.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you know how big the `vector`s will eventually get, just add an `a.reserve(final_size)` and `a_3d.reserve(final_size)` so it won't be resizing so often, and
2. If you oversimplified your code, and you're really making a separate `a` for each `push_back` to `a_3d`, and resetting `a` to empty before populating the next `a`, change `a_3d.push_back(a);` to `a_3d.push_back(std::move(a));`; the latter is a handful of `O(1)` pointer moves that empties `a`, the former is `O(n)` copy work that is unnecessary if the current contents of `a` won't be used again.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the requirement of amortized constant complexity for `push_back`, the allocation strategy is required to allocate memory in factors. For example it is possible to start out with a 1-sized vector and the next reallocations lead to capacities 3,9,27, etc... Because your requested total size is not necessarily a power of this factor, this might waste a lot of memory. You could eg end up with a vector with 27 capacity but only 10 elements.

Long story short: reserve just the right amount of memory

```
a.reserve(N_a);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N_a; i++)
    a.push_back(b);

a_3d.reserve(N_a3);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N_a3; i++)
    a_3d.push_back(a);
```

Note that a 3 fold nested vector isnt the best data structure to begin with. The big plus of a vector is data locality of its elements. The `double`s in your nested vectors however are not contiguous. Consider to use a flat 1-d `std::vector<double>`.